# VSTS Default Agent build fails angular 5 App

Tags: node.js, azure-pipelines, angular5, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to build angular 5 App on VSTS default agent, but it fails. I used hosted agent it show version error saying it's not up to date. Is there any way to do this.

`2018-01-01T19:04:36.3676392Z 17 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3676620Z 18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build" "--prod"
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3676866Z 19 error node v6.9.1
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3677050Z 20 error npm  v3.10.8
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3677231Z 21 error code ELIFECYCLE
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3677432Z 22 error pet-sys@0.0.0 build:`ng build
`2018-01-01T19:04:36.3677619Z 22 error Exit status 1
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3677814Z 23 error Failed at the pet-sys@0.0.0 build script 'ng build'.
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3678039Z 23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3678253Z 23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pet-sys package,
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3678452Z 23 error not with npm itself.
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3678673Z 23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3678861Z 23 error     ng build
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3679058Z 23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3679278Z 23 error     npm bugs pet-sys
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3679477Z 23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3679673Z 23 error     npm owner ls pet-sys
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3679886Z 23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-01-01T19:04:36.3680079Z 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]'`

following link contain all logs for hosted agent build

[logs_597](https://cisintlcom-my.sharepoint.com/personal/amithw_eteknowledge_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=162637341dea34dc7a842b01884babb39&authkey=AWVzIQLUtbxm8x5E9m1z_6Q&expiration=2018-07-02T04%3A13%3A26.000Z&e=5e39ec50697c4e4e9a9429ac43a5db59)

After that I tried to use my default agent which is hosted in my server which has installed latest node and npm and I update the CAPABILITIES as follows

[CAPABILITIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJoIS.png)

then I tried to build using that agent and it show an error,

[logs_602](https://cisintlcom-my.sharepoint.com/personal/amithw_eteknowledge_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=1efab7ea0aeab4b92afd3b544d5756862&authkey=AaglVEKCLYLdS9GB0G1MQmg&expiration=2018-07-02T04%3A21%3A37.000Z&e=8bff4c5497d743a6a68a1c798a774207)

Comment: What's your build definition? Can you show the whole build logs here?

Comment: **@MarinaLiu-MSFT** I have update the logs

Comment: Can you compare the version of @angular/cli you specified in package.json matches the version you installed on build agent machine? And can you also show your app in one drive?

Comment: in my build agent machine and the project version are same so locally I can build but I don't know how to add that to my build agent.@MarinaLiu-MSFT

Comment: If you can help me to create new build agent which support both node and msbuild I really appreciate.@MarinaLiu-MSFT

Comment: link for the package.json [link](https://cisintlcom-my.sharepoint.com/personal/amithw_eteknowledge_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=1a10014c0884e473caca09bc054a6a51d&authkey=AQ1ywF6ddOc6yk3aZ870wxY&expiration=2018-07-02T08%3A27%3A02.000Z&e=49e37820552c4b26840a5ceaa2644201)

Comment: If you can build successful locally, queue build with the build agent which  located on you local machine should be succeed. Doesn't your default agent local on your local machine?

Comment: I added the way to check the version of angular/cli which you installed in VSTS, you can have a try. And I also give the way to create a private agent, you can refer.

Comment: Can you build successful now?

Comment: Thanks @MarinaLiu-MSFT This was very helpful. I have created a new Agent.Is there any ways to update already created agent then install the nodejs

Comment: Yes, there are two ways for an existing agent. **Option 1**: add node.js in agent capability. As the example https://imgur.com/a/hEf9E. **Option 2**: reconfig the existing agent. Remove the current configuration by `./config.cmd remove`, and then config again by `./config.cmd`.

Comment: I tried option 2 It worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure the version for angular/cli package in your `package.json` (you are using `1.6.1`) matches with the installed package in Angular cli install task (which mainly installed the latest version `1.6.3`).

To double check the version you installed in VSTS agent, you can add a `Command Line task` after Angular cli install task. Settings for Command Line task as below:

[image]

If the version is really `1.6.3`, you should change the angular/cli version in `package.json` also as `1.6.3`. Then build again in VSTS.

---

Besides, if you build your app succeed in local machine, you can create a private agent which located in the same local machine, then remove the  Angular cli install task in your VSTS build definition, and then build by the private agent, it should also build successful.

The way to create a private agent as below:

1. Create a PAT with all scopes authorized (if you already have, then skip this step):

   In Security page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_details/security/tokens) -> Add -> input description -> Create Token -> copy the new generated token.
2. Config agent:

   In Agent Pools page, you can create New pool -> Download agent -> unzip the download .zip file -> run powershell as Administrator -> cd /unzip/folder -> then start config a private agent:

   ./config,cmd

   # input URL (https://account.visualstudio.com), PAT, agent pool name as the command hints
3. Check if the new agent you created is online:

   In Agent Pools page -> select the new created -> check if it’s online -> If offline -> input `./run.cmd` in powershell window.

More details about config private agent, you can refer [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows).